# Nuxt PWA with themes based on api informations

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, dynamic-programming, progressive-web-apps, theming

As part of an agency project, we are working on a PWA that needs to be able to change its theme if an api tells it to.

The pwa already builds its manifest.json from the information returned by our api (via a nuxt plugin executed before rendering).

For theming we have several tracks but this deposit seems to be a good example of what is feasible : https://github.com/adrianjost/nuxtjs-theming

Is it possible via a nuxt plugin (or a module via hooks) to modify the currently selected theme? (i.e. to tell our PWA to get its views first in the selected theme folder) ?

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, it looks like this is not doable with `@nuxtjs/pwa` module, but you can maybe get some inspiration to make your own solution.

Give a read to this answer and the thread overall: https://github.com/nuxt-community/pwa-module/issues/225#issuecomment-769880254

Having to manually handle workbox may be a solution: https://github.com/nuxt-community/pwa-module/issues/459 or use a totally hand-made solution of course.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, for the manifest we used a similar technique. For the theming based on API information, we put it aside for the moment, we continue to explore solutions (that fit our needs) to not go through a rebuild of the application each time but if it is necessary we will continue to rebuild our application via jenkins (as we did in v1).